# Can't resolve all parameters for ModalPage: ([object Object], [object Object], ?, [object Object])

Tags: angularjs, ionic3

I am working on Ionic 3.9.2 and facing this error when I trigger a Modal template:

```
Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for ModalPage: ([object Object], [object Object], ?, [object Object]).
```

This class has a function `openModal` which breaks to above mentioned error:

```
import { Component, NgZone } from "@angular/core"
import { NavController, Platform, ModalController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http';
import { ModalPage } from './../modal/modal';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class Component{
  todoItems: object[];
  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public platform: Platform
    public modalCtrl: ModalController
  ) {}

openModal() {
    //This line throws the error
    let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(ModalPage);
  }
```

}

Which angular dependency I am exactly missing?

Comment: Might be that is the cause of wrong `import` path for `ModalPage`

Comment: The path is correct

Comment: You should maybe look at what your modal is injecting

Comment: If below solution did not work for you then have a look at: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic2-starter-aws/issues/34

Answer (score 0):

```
constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public platform: Platform
   @Inject(ModalController) public modalCtrl: ModalController
  )
```

With this you are saying to compiler that missing class will be injected at later point.

Also, important is to say that ModalPage itself should be decorated with @Injectable().

```
@Injectable()
export class ModalPage{
// ... your code
}
```